# My href attribute in my dropdown menu list is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu list for my website that I'm working on my own. While I was making a dropdown list for my website, I ran into some problems. When I try to click one of the list in my dropdown menu, it doesn't head or open to the page where the href attribute is referencing it to. The same goes to all of my lists in my dropdown menu. How can I solve this problem so that my href links will work for each of my list?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 30;
  background-color: #5D5C61;
  background-size: cover;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  height: 9%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  background: #C5C6C7;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.dropdown h2 {
  font-size: 60;
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  top: 3;
  padding: 0px;
}

.brands,
.sneakers,
.gears {
  position: relative;
}

.brands ul,
.sneakers ul,
.gears ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 155%;
  background: #C5C6C7;
  margin-top: 18px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 210px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.brands a,
.sneakers a,
.gears a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.brands li,
.sneakers li,
.gears li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.brands li:hover,
.sneakers li:hover,
.gears li:hover {
  background: #c6c0dd;
}

.dropdown button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown button:hover {
  color: grey;
}

.dropdown h2 a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.brands button:focus+ul,
.sneakers button:focus+ul,
.gears button:focus+ul {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.brands button {
  position: relative;
  left: 53px;
}

.sneakers button {
  position: relative;
  left: 48px;
}

.gears button {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fb27f216f1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <h2><a href="test.html">RBZ</a></h2>
    <div class="brands">
      <button>BRANDS</button>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="nikebrands.html">NIKE</a></li>
        <li><a href="nike.com">ADIDAS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">JORDAN</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="sneakers">
      <button>SNEAKERS</button>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="microsoft.com">NIKE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ADIDAS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">JORDAN</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="gears">
      <button>GEAR & APPAREL</button>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="playstation.com">BACKPACK</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CLOTHES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ACCESSORIES</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: What do you mean `<a href="something.html">` is not working, it works on all browsers, it is a basic feature in the web, Try adding some padding to your anchor tag, anchor tags are inline elements that you have to click on the text to work unless you add some padding.

Comment: Surprisingly, the href attribute doesn't work in my dropdown menu, but it works on most of my code except for the dropdown menu. Also, what properties of padding are you referencing to? Because when I add some properties of padding, like initial and inherit, my href links in my dropdown menu still won't work.

Comment: The problem is in your CSS focus John have posted the answer already, or alternatively you can use JS to add a active class. there are a lot of free tutorials on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with using `focus` to display your dropdown menu.  The moment you click away from your button, i.e. you click your link on your menu, it is no longer in focus and thus your dropdown menu disappears.  I would recommend using an `onclick` function or using a checkbox instead of a button to achieve what you want.

Here's an example using the checkbox method.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 30;
  background-color: #5D5C61;
  background-size: cover;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  height: 9%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  background: #C5C6C7;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.dropdown h2 {
  font-size: 60;
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  top: 3;
  padding: 0px;
}

.brands,
.sneakers,
.gears {
  position: relative;
}

.brands ul,
.sneakers ul,
.gears ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 155%;
  background: #C5C6C7;
  margin-top: 18px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 210px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.brands a,
.sneakers a,
.gears a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.brands li,
.sneakers li,
.gears li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.brands li:hover,
.sneakers li:hover,
.gears li:hover, .box:hover {
  background: #c6c0dd;
}

.box {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box:hover {
  color: grey;
}

.dropdown h2 a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.box input {
  display: none;
}


.box input:checked +ul{
  display: flex;
  pointer-events: all;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}


.brands button {
  position: relative;
  left: 53px;
}

.sneakers button {
  position: relative;
  left: 48px;
}

.gears button {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fb27f216f1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <h2><a href="test.html">RBZ</a></h2>
    <div class="brands">
    
<label class="box">BRANDS
  <input type="checkbox" >
      <ul>
        <li><a href="google.com">NIKE</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.nike.com/">ADIDAS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">JORDAN</a></li>
      </ul>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="sneakers">
    <label class="box">SNEAKERS
  <input type="checkbox" >
      <ul>
        <li><a href="microsoft.com">NIKE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ADIDAS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">JORDAN</a></li>
      </ul>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="gears">
    
        <label class="box">GEAR & APPAREL
  <input type="checkbox" >
      <ul>
        <li><a href="playstation.com">BACKPACK</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CLOTHES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ACCESSORIES</a></li>
      </ul>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: The `a` tag should be used with caution inside a `label` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Interactive_content

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `pointer-events`, specifically `pointer-events:all`, [which is experimental and only applies to SVG anyway](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events). Use `pointer-events:auto` instead.

Also as John mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334345/4665), you are going to get race conditions on click of another element like a link with the use of focus on the button. Your overall approach to this should be reconsidered.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 30;
  background-color: #5D5C61;
  background-size: cover;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  height: 9%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  background: #C5C6C7;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.dropdown h2 {
  font-size: 60;
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  top: 3;
  padding: 0px;
}

.brands,
.sneakers,
.gears {
  position: relative;
}

.brands ul,
.sneakers ul,
.gears ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 155%;
  background: #C5C6C7;
  margin-top: 18px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 210px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  opacity: 0;
  /*pointer-events: none;*/
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.brands a,
.sneakers a,
.gears a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.brands li,
.sneakers li,
.gears li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.brands li:hover,
.sneakers li:hover,
.gears li:hover {
  background: #c6c0dd;
}

.dropdown button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown button:hover {
  color: grey;
}

.dropdown h2 a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.brands button:focus+ul,
.sneakers button:focus+ul,
.gears button:focus+ul {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.brands button {
  position: relative;
  left: 53px;
}

.sneakers button {
  position: relative;
  left: 48px;
}

.gears button {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fb27f216f1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <h2><a href="test.html">RBZ</a></h2>
    <div class="brands">
      <button>BRANDS</button>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="nikebrands.html">NIKE</a></li>
        <li><a href="nike.com">ADIDAS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">JORDAN</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="sneakers">
      <button>SNEAKERS</button>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="microsoft.com">NIKE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ADIDAS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">JORDAN</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="gears">
      <button>GEAR & APPAREL</button>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="playstation.com">BACKPACK</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CLOTHES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ACCESSORIES</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from your css . Remove this line pointer-events: none;
The pointer-events property allows for control over how HTML elements respond to mouse/touch events – including CSS hover/active states, click/tap events in Javascript, and whether or not the cursor is visible